# CORS HttpChannel, how to give the right headers?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, vb.net, http

There is an extension for Google Chrome that sends XML-RPC data to the server. The server XML-RPC is a desktop .NET app.

Here's the code to initialize the server:

```
Dim properties As IDictionary = New Hashtable

properties.Item("name") = "hostChannel"
properties.Item("port") = 5678

Dim chnl As New HttpChannel(properties, Nothing, New XmlRpcServerFormatterSinkProvider)

Try

    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chnl, False)

    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(GetType(StateNameServer), "statename.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton)
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(GetType(CoderServer), "statename.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton)

Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка")

End Try
```

When sending ajax request to that server protection gives CORS not work correctly and causes an error in the add-in.

For this to work it is necessary that the server gave the correct header. And on OPTIONS request from the browser responded with code `200 OK`.

For web server based on Apache this problem has been resolved `.htaccess` file in domain root with the following contents.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blank.php [QSA,L]
```

How to solve this problem for the aforementioned `HttpChannel` ?